# Using handlebars lookup helper to get a property on an object

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to use the lookup helper in handlebars on an object to build a tournament bracket generator.  I'm using a SQL database to store and retrieve all of the information needed to build a bracket.  The problem seems to be that when I get the data into hbs, it's coming as an object and when I try to use the lookup helper, it doesn't want to let me access it in the normal meow.woof format.
Here's my code:

```
          {{#for 0 8 1}}
            <div class="bracket-matchup">
            {{#if (modulus2 this)}}
              <div class="bracket-team winner">
                <div class="bracket-name">{{lookup ../participant.name this}}</div>
              </div>
            {{else}}
              <div class="bracket-team loser">
                <div class="bracket-name">{{lookup ../participant.name this}}</div>
              </div>
            {{/if}}
            </div>
          {{/for}}
```

I wrote helper functions for a simple for loop and modulus so that I can open and close the 's right.  The "this" in the lookup refers to the index of the for loop.  I've tried changing the data coming in to hbs to only have the data I need to spit out the name so that I can just use `{{lookup ../participant this}}`, but then when I do that, the output is [object, Object]

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you're trying to do if you had a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, can you update your question so that it doesn't rely on custom helpers, and include some sample context data that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that `participant` is an array of objects that each contain a `name` property, and that what you're trying to get the name of the participant at the position indicated by `this` in the array. Then I think you are misapprehending the usage of `lookup`. I think what you want is this:

```
        {{#for 0 8 1}}
          <div class="bracket-matchup">
            {{#if (modulus2 this)}}
              <div class="bracket-team winner">
                <div class="bracket-name">
                  {{#with (lookup ../participant this)}}
                    {{name}}
                  {{/with}}
                </div>
              </div>
            {{else}}
              <div class="bracket-team loser">
                <div class="bracket-name">
                  {{#with (lookup ../participant this)}}
                    {{name}}
                  {{/with}}
                </div>
              </div>
            {{/if}}
          </div>
        {{/for}}
```

That said, if this is the type of data structure you're working with, you might want to drop the use of your `#for` helper, and use `#each` instead, with which you can use `@index` when using your `modulus2` helper.